# Endermites Do Not Spawn

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wandering through my Minecraft World and I didn’t find any endermites or silverfish. I didn’t want to summon them because I didn’t want to attract attention to myself.

Comment: Are you in peaceful mode?

Comment: No, I am on easy.

Comment: And thank you @Ari, But I have found silverfish not in strongholds in previous worlds.

Comment: if i answered your question, dont forget to click the check mark next to my answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverfish spawn from the spawner in a stronghold, or in extreme hills some of the stone will be infested, meaning when broken they will spawn silverfish.

Endermites have a 1/16 (6.25%) chance to spawn when an ender pearl lands.

Answer (score 1):

As far as im aware of, silverfish can only spawn in strongholds.
Endermites have a chance of spawning when you throw an ender pearl. If an endermite does spawn, you can find it near where the ender pearl landed after you've thrown it.
However, you can just spawn in said mobs using the spawn eggs in creative mode.

Comment: Silverfish can also spawn in mountain biomes as well as igloo basements. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Silverfish

Comment: @KyleRone ah! Terribly sorry. Im not the most "in the know" when it comes to all of minecraft. My mistake. :')

Comment: no worries man! I just learned about this like a week ago when I happened to be strip mining and ran into those silvery bastards.

Comment: @KyleRone oof, thats sucks. I hate silverfish. I hope you got diamonds tho!